# AlpacaJS: programmatically change value of TextField after selecting Select

Tags: alpacajs

I'm new to AlpacaJS and getting crazy trying to figure out how to do a simple stuff like changing dinamically the content of a text field with the value of a "Select".

The code looks like

```
$("#form1").alpaca({
    "data": {
        "name": "Default"
    },
    "schema": {
        "title": "What do you think of Alpaca?",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "title": "Name"
            },
            "flavour":{
                "type": "select",
                "title": "Flavour",
                "enum": ["vanilla", "chocolate", "coffee", "strawberry", "mint"]
            }

        }
    },
    "options": {
        "helper": "Tell us what you think about Alpaca!",
            "flavour": {
                "type": "select",
                "helper": "Select your flavour.",
                "optionLabels": ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Coffee", "Strawberry", "Mint"]
            }            
        }
    },
    "postRender": function(control) {
        var flavour = control.childrenByPropertyId["flavour"];
        var name = control.childrenByPropertyId["name"];
        name.subscribe(flavour, function(val) {
            alert("Val = " + val);
            this.schema.data = val;
            this.refresh();
        });

    }    
});
```

I can see that the function in postRenderer is called (as I can see the alert with relevant value) but (maybe I'm brain dead at this stage) I cannot refresh the text field with that value.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was probably looking at the wrong attribute to be set... After I changed to

```
this.schema.data = val;
```

it worked fine :)